# Переопределение currencyFormat в настройках локали Yii

Tags: framework, yii

У приложения существует свойство `numberFormatter`, у которого есть метод для форматирования числа и валюты в соответствии с настройками локали `formatCurrency()`.

Настройки локали хранятся в файлах интернализации, и разработчики предлагают в конфиге приложения указывать путь к кастомному файлу интернационализации для изменения в нем данных.

Но мне нужно изменить 2 символа для изменения `currencyFormat` (отбросить числа после запятой) и из-за этого очень не хочется копировать целый файл.

Может, существует другой способ изменить `currencyFormat`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20745904 вот такой вариант есть, но это вообще для всего сайта получится

Comment: Спасибо! Боюсь, править исходники yii мне не подходит, несмотря на баг.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант, без правки исходников, только в этом случае на всех языках цифра будет выглядеть одинаково, потому что жёстко задаётся pattern для её отображения:

    Yii::app()->NumberFormatter->format( "#,##0", $value, $currency);

Comment: Это да, мне бы больше хотелось паттерн определить в одном месте и обращаться к нему там, где надо. Можно определить константу, но если есть стандартные средства, то хотелось бы использовать их. В любом случае я уже воспользовался предложением разработчиков - создал кастомный файл с настройками локали.